# Should I use forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

My web application allows our clients to configure some settings on the products we are selling them. Some settings require a premium account to be accessed. I'm using Asp.Net roles to restrain access to these "premium settings".

My problem is that a user account must be able to configure settings for multiple clients. In this case, plain Asp.net roles will not suffice as access will be conditioned by a role on a particular client. Some clients may have premium access where others don't.

I need to keep forms authentication, as I don't have the time or experience to roll out my own authentication system.

What's the standard approach to this kind of problem ?

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what a "setting" is here, or what the difference is between a "user" and "client" or what you mean by "configure settings for multiple clients" and how premium vs non-premium applies to the situation.  We can't help you with such a vague description.  Further, are you actually using forms authentication or are you using ASP.NET Identity?  What version of MVC?

Comment: The products are web applications we are selling to the clients (SaaS). The settings could be for example, "display ads in the web app" or "change the css in my app". Some are free, and for some you need to pay extra. A user has a login and password, a client is the company paying for the services. A single user can be in charge of multiple clients with the same account. Running on MVC4 so using forms auth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authorization-in-ASP.Net-MVC.html